# portList.hasMoreElements() is getting false on serial port reading

Tags: java, 64-bit, windows-8.1, enumeration, rxtx

I have the following program to read and list the serial port,

```
import gnu.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Connectnow implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {

    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static Enumeration portList;

    InputStream inputStream;
    SerialPort serialPort;
    Thread readThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        System.out.println("portList=" + portList);
        System.out.println(portList.hasMoreElements());
        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
            CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier)portList.nextElement();
            System.out.println("portId=" + portId);
        }
    }


    public void run() {
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent ev) {
    }
}
```

I am using RXTX library for it.

I have compiled and run the java program as follows:

```
C:\SMS\work>javac Connectnow.java

C:\SMS\work>java Connectnow
portList=gnu.io.CommPortEnumerator@5e481248
false
```

I am getting the value of `portList.hasMoreElements()` as `false`. What to do? I have set all the things in the RXTX library correctly. I am using Windows 8.1 64bit system. Please help me. Why it is coming as false?